# Change Y variable to factor, losing information

Tags: r, target

Iam trying a machine learning task. Therefore, i have to transform my data.

The target variable is numeric: e.g.:

```
df$target
9.0
8.0
6.0
6.5
```

But the numbers were to close to each others (there were no insufficiënt numbers). Therefore i changed the numbers in:

```
> df$target <- cut(df$target, 4) 
> levels(df$target) <- c("Bad", "Neutral", "Good", "Amazing")
```

Class = numeric, so I made them a factor (that is needed for ML):

> df$target <- as.factor(df$target)

But when I checked the labels, it is interesting to see that they do not respond with the levels as I made, but with:

```
>unique(df$target) 
>[1] 42613 42475 42399 42536 42735 42521
```

I need the target to be only 4 unique labels: Bad, Neutral, Good and Amazing. How is it possible that it isn't working? And even better: how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I tried with your method `df$target1 <- cut(df$target, 4) 
;levels(df$target1) <- c("Bad", "Neutral", "Good", "Amazing");df$target1#
[1] Amazing Good    Bad     Bad    
Levels: Bad Neutral Good Amazing`  it is not changing to `numeric`.  Did you do anything differently

Comment: Only thing i added: is colnames(df) <- c("....","target")

Comment: `cut` outputs a `factor`, so you woudn't need `df$target <- as.factor(df$target) `. Unless there's something else you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide a minimal reproducible example to get better answers. It seems that you are doing the correct thing which should work, but somehow your data frame is not updated.

This example works for me:

```
# Create come toydata
df <- data.frame(target = rnorm(6))

print(df$target) # A numeric
#[1] -0.6194364  1.8817725  1.2898545  0.8297128  0.7837745  0.1337996

df$target <- cut(df$target, breaks = 4) # Now a factor with 4 levels but with wrong labels
print(df$target)
#[1] (-0.622,0.00587] (1.26,1.88] (1.26,1.88] (0.631,1.26] (0.631,1.26] (0.00587,0.631] 
#Levels: (-0.622,0.00587] (0.00587,0.631] (0.631,1.26] (1.26,1.88]

levels(df$target) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")  # Update labels
print(df$target)
#[1] c1 c4 c4 c3 c3 c2
#Levels: c1 c2 c3 c4
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here... no problem with this code

```
library(data.table)
A = data.table(B = 1:10)
A[,B:= cut(B,4)]
levels(A$B) = letters[1:4]
unique(A$B)
```